# Foreign Key, on delete set null

Tags: mysql

Am I misunderstanding something here? I have two tables, table1 and table2. Table2 has a foreign key that references a field in table1 with `ON DELETE SET NULL` associated with the foreign key. Table2 also has a `TIMESTAMP` field that has `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` set.

Modifying an entry in table2 successfully updates the timestamp field.
Deleting the linked entry in table1 successfully sets the foreign key field in table2 to `NULL`, but does not update the `TIMESTAMP` field in table2.

When the field in in table2 gets set to NULL, isn't that considered an `UPDATE`, and the timestamp should get updated too?

Comment: FKs are not do-all.  It may be better to write your own code and wrap it in a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented, although not very clearly, in [MySQL docs: InnoDB restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> - Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.